# What should be the shape of y-train for LSTM for multi-class classification, given non-textual sequential data?

Tags: keras, time-series, lstm, multiclass-classification

#### Problem Description

I have a dataset (features=175, n_time_steps=954, Number of sequences=737). 
Columns 1-174 are features, the last target column contains 3 different classes. I would like to use LSTM for multi-class classification to predict only the last time step, i.e. use 953 steps and features to predict the class of the step 954. I am struggling with the structure of y_train input. I will appreciate any thoughts on how to reshape the y_train correctly for this problem.

#### Data

I have 737 products, each  has sales for 954 days. The target classes are (0- when the product did not existed, 1-product of typeA, 2 product of type B). I need to use 953 days and 174 features to predict the class of each product  at the last date of  sequence (954). Test set has 100 products, train set -637 products.

After reshaping X_train has (637, 953, 175) shape. y_train has the shape of 
(637, 1). When I run to_categorical the shape is (637, 2). both y_train shapes throw errors when fited to the LSTM model.

When I fit y_train of shape (637, 1), the error is

```
ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (637, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, classes). If your targets are integer classes, you can convert them to the expected format via:

from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)


Alternatively, you can use the loss function `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead, which does expect integer targets.
```

When I fit `to_categorical(y_train)` of shape (637, 2), the error is

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_45 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)
```

When I change to 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' and fit y_train of shape (637,1), the error is

```
InvalidArgumentError: Received a label value of 1 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values: 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     [[{{node loss_13/dense_48_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]
```

Here is my model

```
model = Sequential([
            LSTM(units=1024, 
            input_shape=(periods_to_train,features), kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
            activation ='linear', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3), return_sequences=False),
            Dropout(rate=0.5),
            Dense(units=1024,kernel_initializer='he_uniform', 
            activation='linear', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)),
            Dropout(rate=0.5),
            Dense(units=1024, kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
            activation='linear', kernel_constraint=maxnorm(3)),
            Dropout(rate=0.5),
            Dense(units=periods_to_predict, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='softmax')])

        #Compile model
optimizer = Adamax(lr=0.001, decay=0.1)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

configure(gpu_ind=True)
model.fit(X_train, y_train ,validation_split=0.1, batch_size=100, epochs=8, shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your understanding of the network is correct. So I recreated a minimal working example to generate data and train in the same manner as you do. When I set the time-steps (periods_to_train) equal to 953 as you have, I also get some weird errors. But it has been multiple study suggesting no more than 200 to 500 time-step dependency using LSTM, as the model output will start to "forget" earlier information.

Below is an minimal working example code of what you try to do, using only 100 time-steps. No Errors in my case (tensorflow version 1.14.0):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
import numpy as np


data_size = 637
periods_to_train=100
features = 175
periods_to_predict = 3

X_train=np.random.rand(data_size,periods_to_train,features)
y_train=np.random.randint(0,3,data_size).reshape(-1,1)

K.clear_session()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
                    units=1024, input_shape=(periods_to_train,features), kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
                    activation ='linear', kernel_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.max_norm(3.), return_sequences=False),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(
                    units=1024,kernel_initializer='he_uniform', 
                    activation='linear', kernel_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.max_norm(3)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(
                    units=1024, kernel_initializer='he_uniform',
                    activation='linear', kernel_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.max_norm(3)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(
                    units=periods_to_predict, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', 
                    activation='softmax')])


optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.001, decay=0.1)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train ,validation_split=0.1, batch_size=64, epochs=1, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: thank you KrisR89, I found this overview after reading your post. for future references  [link] https://machinelearningmastery.com/handle-long-sequences-long-short-term-memory-recurrent-neural-networks/